# sphinx autobuild - usage, makefile, extensions

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm working with sphinx for the first time so I'm sure this is simply a problem of understanding the basics, sorry for that.

Using windows, part of `make.bat` looks like this:

```
if "%SPHINXBUILD%" == "" (
    set SPHINXBUILD=sphinx-build
)
set SOURCEDIR=.
set BUILDDIR=_build

if "%1" == "" goto help
if "%1" == "deploy" goto deploy

%SPHINXBUILD% >NUL 2>NUL
if errorlevel 9009 (
    echo.
    echo.The 'sphinx-build' command was not found. Make sure you have Sphinx
    echo.installed, then set the SPHINXBUILD environment variable to point
    echo.to the full path of the 'sphinx-build' executable. Alternatively you
    echo.may add the Sphinx directory to PATH.
    echo.
    echo.If you don't have Sphinx installed, grab it from
    echo.http://sphinx-doc.org/
    exit /b 1
)

%SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
goto end

if "%1" == "livehtml" (
    sphinx-autobuild %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %2
) else (
    %SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %2
)
goto end

:deploy
rmdir /S /Q ..\..\public || true
cp -r _build\html ..\..\public
goto end

:help
%SPHINXBUILD% -M help %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
```

Where I added the part:

```
if "%1" == "livehtml" (
    sphinx-autobuild %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %2
) else (
    %SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %2
)
goto end
```

according to https://bskinn.github.io/Sphinx-Autobuild-Windows/

When I call `make.bat livehtml`, I get the error:

> Builder name livehtml not registered or available through entry point

I googled and this is all I found: https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs-sphinx-ext/issues/27
so it seems like I might have to add the autobuild extension to the `conf.py` file - but how?
Or maybe it's something else?  I did install sphinx-autobuild with pip.

Comment: The documentation for sphinx-autobuild does not say that `extensions` must be populated in conf,py (https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-autobuild). I don't think sphinx-autobuild is a Sphinx extension of the kind described at  https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/index.html.

Comment: @mzjn yeah exactly, I got the same impression. Only tried it because of a similar error

Comment: @bad_coder thanks a lot for that suggestion! I might try that as well. However, as other people will be working on it as well, I definitely need a different solution in the end.

Comment: @bad_coder that is exactly what I did 3 days ago and where I got the error from. Now, having not touched any code and not even my computer on the weekend, it didn't get any error when I just tried building it again. I feel super stupid now. Thanks so much for the effort anyways :) it still doesn't update in the browser but I guess that's an other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sphinx-autobuild is an application that launches a web server and probes changes in your `docs` directory to automatically refresh open pages of the documentation you are developing in your browser.

It's not a Sphinx [extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/index.html) nor does [its documentation](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autobuild/) claim it to be.

The error you got:

> When I call "make.bat livehtml", I get the error: Builder name livehtml not registered or available through entry point

Indicates your changes to the make file had not been saved, when you tried running `make livehtml`. The edit to the make file launches `sphinx-autobuild` instead of the usual `sphinx-build`.  Because `sphinx-build` was being run normally passing `livehtml` as a [buildername](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-b) that could not be found.